# Get around Exponential Integral in indefinite integral calculation?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, elementary-functions

I have two functions, $f(x) = a_0 e^{-a_6 \bigl( x + (a_1 x + a_2) \bigr)}$ and $g(x) = \big| a_3 x^2 + a_4 x + a_5 \bigr|$

I'm trying to find the integral $\int{f(x)/g(x) dx}$.

Wolfram gives this:

$$(a_0 \exp\left(-\frac12 (2 a_2 + \frac{a_1 + 1}{ a_3 } \bigl( \sqrt{a_4^2 - 4 a_3 a_5} - a_4 
\bigr) a_6 \right) (\mathrm{Ei}(-((a_1 + 1) (2 x a_3 + a_4 - \sqrt(a_4^2 - 4 a_3 a_5)) a_6)/(2 a_3)) - e^{(((a_1 + 1) \sqrt(a_4^2 - 4 a_3 a_5) a_6)/a_3)} \mathrm{Ei}(-((a_1 + 1) (2 x a_3 + a_4 + \sqrt(a_4^2 - 4 a_3 a_5)) a_6)/(2 a_3))) \mathrm{sgn}(a_3 x^2 + a_4 x + a_5))/\sqrt(a_4^2 - 4 a_3 a_5) + \mathrm{constant}$$

which is a problem because of **Ei**, the exponential integral. On my platform, computing **Ei** does not really seem feasible. AFAIK there is no "simple" approximation of $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$.

What I might be able to do is transform some of the functions around, since they represent other concepts.  For example $f(x)$ is really just Beer's Law, and $g(x)$ is really just an abstract representation of the area of a triangle whose points are a function of $x$, changing $g(x)$ to $$\frac14 \sqrt{a_3 x^4 + a_4 x^3 + a_5 x^2 + a_6 x + a_7}$$ 
(note I compressed constants together into these $a_n$ terms) if we use herons formula. Unfortunately plugging this into Wolfram gives me nothing.

What is strange is that individually these functions seem to give perfectly normal integrals (using $1/g(x))$, and visually in what I'm trying to compute there's no transcendental-ness going on, so I'm not exactly sure what is causing the need to use **Ei**.  Is there any way I can avoid having these non elementary functions in my integral, or at least only have functions that are relatively easy to compute?

Also note that $x$ is always non-negative, and all constants as well as $x$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see how you could avoid the exponential integral.

Concerning its approximation, for real values of $x$, you could use the expansion
$$\text{Ei}(x)=\gamma+\log (x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n\, n!}$$ which converges quite fast.

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), you will see that Ramanujan proposed a faster convergence expansion
$${\rm Ei} (x) = \gamma + \ln x + e^{\frac x 2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^{n-1} x^n} {n! \, 2^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor} \frac{1}{2k+1}$$ where

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor} \frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2} H_{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{1}{2}}+{\log
   (2)}$$

Comment: What is $H$ here? and what are the constraints under which these are accurate?  Looking at wikipedia it seems they are quite limited.

Comment: @opa. $H_q$ is the harmonic number. It can be as accurate as you want.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, it looked like the approximation may *diverge* for certain values of $x$, which would seem to go against the notion that it can be as accurate as I want.